# Timer stops when screen gets locked Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I made an application for Windows Phone 8 which features a timer. My problem is, that as soon as the phone locks the screen, my timer (and my application I guess) pauses. I don't want to stop the phone from going into lock screen, I want my application to run in background. I can't figure out a 'clean' way to do this.

Comment: What does your timer code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to properly enable your app to continue running under the lock screen. Take a look at:

[Running a Windows Phone Application under the lock screen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/01/running-a-windows-phone-application-under-the-lock-screen.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, the link helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
 PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

put this line under App() constructor of App.xaml.cs page